# Change events on dynamically added selects using the Chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the Chosen plugin on my site, and so far it has been working perfectly. However, I'm in a situation where I added a select dynamically and activated the Chosen plugin on those selects. These Chosen selects are being produced fine, but I cannot figure out how to bind a click event to the element. Chosen offers this( `$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );`) as a way to do something on the change event, however, this does not work since my select was added dynamically.

I have tried `$('#el').change` and  `$(document).on("change", "#el", function())` as well without any success.

Comment: You should be able to use the `.chosen().change()` code after you add the element dynamically.

Comment: Are you creating unique ids for the elements? If you want all the elements to run the same function you could always use a class?

Comment: I am creating unique ids for the elements and using those for the change events. To initialize the plugin I'm using `$(".chosen-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});` Should I also be initializing with the ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original Answer:
From http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events

"If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content."

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

...so just call that after you add the new element.

Edit:
After reviewing this http://jsfiddle.net/amindunited/reh5p0tg/3/
I can see that the issue was that the change() listener for the second select was being attached before that select was added to the page.
I have updated the fiddle code to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/amindunited/reh5p0tg/4/

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what this does, but isn't this only for changing options within the select dynamically rather than adding the entire select dynamically? Either way, I tried it out and it doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: I've created a fiddle, in hopes of better understanding http://jsfiddle.net/amindunited/reh5p0tg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/reh5p0tg/3/ What am I doing differently/wrong in this situation that is keeping the change event from being registered for the second chosen?

Comment: There we are...the 'change' event listener for the second select has to be attached after the it is initialised. http://jsfiddle.net/amindunited/reh5p0tg/4/

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Another way to make it work is to stuff everything inside an init function:

```
function init_new_content(){
  $("#form_field").chosen();
}
init_new_content();
```

And then call it whenever you know you made a change (for example on ajax)

```
$.ajax({...},
            success: function( data){
                     init_new_content();
            },
...
```

Comment: Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler  (which `chosen` can vary easily do).